# How to prevent font blurring when scaling an image down

Tags: fonts, gimp, logo

I'm creating a logo for a Youtube channel and it's a text logo. Youtube suggests you upload the logo at 800x800, so that's what I've been designing at in GIMP and it looks fine:

[image: logo]

However, the actual channel logo (as seen at the bottom of the video) is 98x98. Obviously, Youtube scales it down as needed and I figured I would scale the image down just to see what it would look like when displayed at 98x98. And this is where the issue begins. I designed the logo to utilize a Light variant of the Quicksand font (AEVES), which contrasts with the thicker font below it (TECH).

The issue is in that. When I scale down the image to 98x98, the letters start becoming somewhat fuzzy (someone described them as looking like they're wearing a wool sweater):

[image]

Does this second image (at 98x98) look acceptable? Or, if not, how can I get the text to scale down to 98x98 without becoming fuzzy?

Comment: I would suggest using a vector based program like the free [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) or Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: I actually have been attempting to use Inkscape, but it won't recognize the variant of the Quicksand font which I want, the Light variant. I actually asked another question regarding that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Pass #1 "Get it approximately right" -- Align as many edges of each character as you can to a 4-pixel grid before you resize.

   - If you're pressed for time, the most important edges are the outermost edges of each character, and the horizontal internal edges.

[image: 4x aligned]

2. Shrink, (I used bilinear interpolation), down to 98x98px to check which edges are still blurry:

[image: 98px not yet aligned]

3. Pass #2 "Get it exactly right" -- Undo the shrink (or just cancel the preview), adjust the blurry edges up/right/left/down as appropriate, reshrink to 98px. Repeat until satisfied, and save:

[image: 98px aligned]

4. If you also want a 400px version which comes out crisply when you let the browser shrink it to 98px, then undo your last shrink, and save.

[image: Final result]

Comment: n.b. These instructions were written with Photoshop in mind, however they're hopefully generic enough to apply to GIMP as well.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tested the logo out on the channel that it's intended for, and the text is *far* too small for this version of the logo to be used :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this is correct but would not use of the path from text command resolve the issue? I know in some versions of GIMP this was called create path from text.